# Trigger Specific Jenkins Job on Github Push to specific Directory

Tags: git, github, jenkins, githooks

I have several Jenkins Job running which Deploy's code to application server. These jobs run automatically whenever there is Commit in Github repository configured through Jenkins Plugin in Github and webhook. Jenkins is running on a Windows system.

We have several applications in the repository, represented by a directory containing the code, each of these applications have a corresponding Jenkins Job which deploy's the code to server when the Job is run.
Since all the applications are in the same repository, so change in any one of the application creates a Push event and thus trigers all the Jobs.

Suppose there are three Applications **App1**, **App2** and **App3** and their corresponding Jobs are **J1**, **J2**, **J3**
and  there is a change in App1 and a commit is made in Github repository it causes all the Jobs **J1**,**J2**,**J3** to trigger and Deploys **App1**, **App2**, **App3** in server.

It causes unnecessary confusion since **App2**, **App3** do not have any changes in repository but still gets deployed to server.
Is there any way that i can trigger specific Jenkins job build based on Directory level Changes/Commits in the Github repository. Can we use any git hooks somehow to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

For that to happen, You can sparse checkout to a specific directory in the git so that every jenkins job will be mutual to each other.

> jenkins job configure -> Source Code Management -> Git -> Additional Behaviours -> Add -> Sparse Checkout paths

This will simply sparse checkout to a sub directory and checks if there are any commits on that directory only. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please specify how is your job in jenkins configured.

Comment: The Jenkins Job is configured with "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" option so that the Job gets triggered on a GITHUB PUSH event.

Comment: On using this Check out to a sub-directory feature, even though checkout happens to a sub-directory but still the Trigger mechanism is same i.e. All Jobs gets triggered if any Push happens in GitHub Repository. I need to avoid triggering other Jobs which also gets triggered using Github hook.

Comment: I have changed the answer please check. I hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Tried "Sparse Checkout Paths" , that too didn't work. All the jobs still gets triggered even though only a particular folder gets checked out

Comment: Simply give a url for each jenkins job and call it with git hook from server side. So that only specific job will be triggered. For git hooks docs, refer this. [https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke3f3rcRSc8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke3f3rcRSc8) this video can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been spend 4 days to resolve this issue. this is mine that actually works

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        // custom your own environment
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("Clone Repository") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Clone ${DIRECTORY} repository..."
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${BRANCH}"]],
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                        extensions: [[$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths', sparseCheckoutPaths: [[path: env.DIRECTORY]]]],
                        submoduleCfg: [],
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_CREDENTIALS}", url: "${GIT_REPO}"]]])
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage("Check Changes") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Check changes ${DIRECTORY}..."
                    def changes = checkForChanges(env.DIRECTORY)
                    if (changes) {
                        echo "Changes detected in ${DIRECTORY}."
                        env.BUILD_IMAGE_CHANGED = "true"
                    } else {
                        currentBuild.result = 'NOT_BUILT'
                        echo "No changes detected in ${DIRECTORY}. Skipping build."
                        env.BUILD_IMAGE_CHANGED = "false"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage("Build Image") {
            when {
                expression { return env.BUILD_IMAGE_CHANGED == "true" }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Building ${DIRECTORY} image..."
                    sh 'docker build -t $IMAGE -f ${DIRECTORY}/Dockerfile .'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def checkForChanges(dir) {
    def diff = sh(script: "git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only | grep ${dir}", returnStatus: true)
    return diff == 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**